# Converting pd.DataFrame into np.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a question about converting DataFrame into np.array.

I converted DataFrame into array through the code below,
but all the figures in df changed their position of the decimal points after converting. How can I save the format of them?df contains int64 and float64.

```
 import os
 import pandas as pd 
 import numpy as np

 df = pd.read_csv("***.csv", header=0, parse_dates=['date'])

 xset = np.array(df)
```

※As output of df
124.63 1215.93 20.56

※As output of xset
([[  1.24630000e+02,   1.21593000e+03,   2.05600000e+01, ...,

Comment: These are the same numbers...

Comment: You can use df.values

Answer (score 0):

you can use np.array(df.values)

Comment: Just `df.values` will work.